# Derivation of the Pnl of a Delta Hedged Straddle and Risk Reversal

Tags: options, volatility, greeks, vega, risk-premium

In the link below, in the text it states the following equations:

> Delta-hedged straddle  P&L = Volatility Risk-premium
>   ×|
>   Straddle  Vega
>   |

and

> Delta-hedged risk-reversal  P&L:
>   P&L = Skew Risk-premium
>   ×
>   Risk-Reversal Vanna

How has this been derived and where has it come from?

See https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=815017127117093113006113095103078023063027086039084088067084004023007116112070065104099039034045048124109003098024069094119066005070053014040089118024028001008124028069045045005087113000002023103004002080023080121123110097126110114082083111115123091085&EXT=pdf .

Comment: your pdf link isn't working for me

Comment: @pyCthon "SSRN will be unavailable until 9.00 EST on Monday August 13th." on the SSRN website. This hopefully is the issue

Comment: @pyCthon the slides are called "Gaining the alpha advantage in volatility trading" by Artur Sepp

Comment: It's just derived using the black scholes framework

Comment: @pyCthon which is how......